# Javascript: Difference between writing property of a class in a concstructor or outside of it?

Tags: javascript, class, javascript-objects

What is the difference between writing property inside a class constructor or outside of it?

For example, what is the difference in writing property "legs" in these two examples:

1)

```
class Rabbit{
  constructor(){
  this.legs= 4
  }
}
```

2)

```
 class Rabbit{
   legs = 4;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Second option needs [babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) plugin and first does not need that.

Answer (score 0):

To use `property` dynamically in the class.Think that way, `constructor` change or assign property whenever `class` instantiate with any value. And property outside of constructor are default.if we don't write any constructor definition in the class,it will not be able get new value with in instantiate. Constructor function/method will fired whenever we instantiate that class,it will construct everything as we need or as we want.

```
    class Rabbit{
      legs= 4

      constructor(lg){
         this.legs= lg
      }
    }
const r = new Rabbit(2);//we override its value 4 to 2
```

And

```
    class Rabbit{
       legs = 4;
     }
const r = new Rabbit(3);//we don't override its value 4 to 3,it will be 4
```

Comment: Yes, I know that we can use property dynamically only by using the constructor. 
In your first example, we could also write default value in the constructor and not to use property legs outside of the class at all.

    `class Rabbit{

          constructor(lg = 4){

             this.legs= lg

          }

        }`

Comment: In case,we don't give any arguments with instantiate,it will use default values.If It has purpose in your class,you will use it in your constructor; otherwise you don't need to use it.

Comment: I try to find the answer to what the difference between whether to write property(outside constructor or inside) if we don't need to set property dynamically.
As long as I see from another reply, the only difference is regarding Babel, isn't it?

Comment: Difference is clear,if you don't want to override its default value,don't need to assign in constructor function.

Comment: I understand that if I don't want to override a property's default value, I can do it in both ways. What I try to figure out if there is any difference in these 2 cases (How JavaScript works with it)

Comment: No,You can't override in both ways.if you want to assign new value to any property,you need to assign through construction function to get from initiate.

Comment: I mean that if I don't want to override a property's default value, I can write the property both inside a constructor or outside the constructor. What I try to figure out if there is any difference how Javascript interprets writing the property inside the constructor or outside of the constructor.

Comment: Yes,you can.if you don't need to assign new value to a property,it was purposeless to put it in a  construction function,it should be outside of constructor. However,if you want to put it in constructor without any purpose,there is no problem- class functioning will not give any error.

Comment: If you think my answer is acceptable,please don't forget to accept it as a answer. It will be appreciated.thanks